# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This issue is occurring when my page loads.

Using the following scripts 
-jquery.simplemodal-1.4.3.js
-jquery  v1.7.1

Below is a small code snap, of the code inside simplemodal where this error is occuring.

```
 focus: function (pos) {  
 var s = this, p = pos && $.inArray(pos, ['first', 'last']) !== -1 ? pos : 'first';
     // focus on dialog or the first visible/enabled input element
       var input = $(':input:enabled:visible:' + p, s.d.wrap);
       setTimeout(function () {
    input.length > 0 ? input.focus() : s.d.wrap.focus();
    }, 10);
  },
```

Any Ideas that i could do to resolve this would be great

Comment: Open the developer tools, javascript debugger, and try to find exactly what variable in your code is undefined.

Comment: its coming from the s.d.wrap.focus();

Comment: Probably you run your function before the document is loaded. MAybe it should be wrapped in `$(function(){ ... })`. Or after the modal is visible.

Comment: hmmmmmm any other ideas ?

Comment: You call your `focus` method when the modal is not visible. It's evident. Find a place where you call this method and try to call it after showing of that modal.

Comment: @vorrtex - how to check if modal is visible?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question and the original poster has probably resolved his concrete issue.
But the general questions related to the Error Messages:

- **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined**
- **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of null**
  and
- **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '...' of undefined**
- **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '...' of null**

are still important for many peoples and have a simple and general answer:

> The object of that we try to read property, set property or call a function
>    - is not declared or
>    - is declared, but not defined or
>    - is null

Simple test code in Google Chrome

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// object obj is not declared, there is no previos 'var obj;'
obj.prop;              // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined
obj.prop = "value1";   // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'prop' of undefined
obj.func();            // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// object 'obj' is declared with:
var obj;
// but it is not defined, there is no value assigned to it (obj = 5 or something else)
obj.prop;              // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined
obj.prop = "value1";   // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'prop' of undefined
obj.func();            // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of undefined
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// object 'obj' is declared and defined. Value is null
var obj = null;
obj.prop;              // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of null
obj.prop = "value1";   // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'prop' of null
obj.func();            // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'func' of null
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// object 'obj' is declared and defined
var obj = {prop: "propertyValue", func: function() {return "returnValue"}}
// there are no errors
</script>
```

The same code in Firefox:

```
// object obj is not declared, there is no previos 'var obj;'
obj.prop;              // Uncaught TypeError: obj is undefined
obj.prop = "value1";   // Uncaught TypeError: obj is undefined
obj.func();            // Uncaught TypeError: obj is undefined
-----------------------------------
// object 'obj' is declared with:
var obj;
// but it is not defined, there is no value assigned to it (obj = 5 or something else)
obj.prop;              // Uncaught TypeError: obj is undefined
obj.prop = "value1";   // Uncaught TypeError: obj is undefined
obj.func();            // Uncaught TypeError: obj is undefined
-----------------------------------
// object 'obj' is declared and defined. Value is null
var obj = null;
obj.prop;              // Uncaught TypeError: obj is null
obj.prop = "value1";   // Uncaught TypeError: obj is null
obj.func();            // Uncaught TypeError: obj is null
-----------------------------------
// object 'obj' is declared and defined
var obj = {prop: "propertyValue", func: function() {return "returnValue"}}
// there are no errors
```

So there are some differences in the Error Message between browser, but the massage is clear:

> The object in not defined or null.

In the general case it is easy to understand what exactly the error message means.

**But why this happens in concrete cases?**

The reasons could by many, but the important ones could be:

- Calling a function or accessing a property

  - before it is initialized/defined
    These could happen, if an object (popup, modal), created on the fly, is not ready yet.
  - after it is destroyed
- Structure changes by using new versions of an API, where a property or function was

  - renamed or
  - moved to other objects
- By using loops on arrays:  the index don't exist, because of

  - bad incrementation/decrementation or
  - bad condition

**How to debug?**

- Find on which object and where the error is thrown
- Read the documentation to assure that,

  - try using the object on the right place,
  - have called all needed functions, before using the object
- Look in the scope/function if the object is defined,
- If not, look in the stacktrace in its caller(s)...